# Fail to install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows XP Embedded

Tags: windows, .net, windows-xp

I've a XP Embedded device on which I tried to install the Full 3.5 Framework (not the Compact one) but doesn't work because the size of the hard disk drive is to small (only ~200MB left).

1) Can I "partially" install the .NET Framework ? (Where I choose the stuff I need and not)
2) If installing the Compact Framework instead, can I use an application compiled for WinCE?

Thanks for any constructive hint.

Comment: If application is written for WinCE, install Compact framework to your XPE device and it should be fine.

Comment: I've tried but doesn't work, it says me that the application can't be launched normally...

Comment: There is a Fx3.5 Client Profile, but I doubt if it runs on Embedded. CE + CF seems the way.

Comment: Hmm strange...as i remember I could run my WinCE application in Windows XP(it was 4-3 years ago)...maybe I ran it in emulator or with full .NET Framework. Also I found interesting post [here](http://superuser.com/questions/278775/how-to-launch-wince-app-on-windows-xp)